# What effect does airflow rate have on heat dissipation if the initial heat varies proportionally to the airflow rate?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, temperature, convection, heat

If I have a server rack consuming 10 kW of power in an empty room with A/C, what effect does the rate of airflow from the rack's exhaust have on the temperature in the room and the load on the HVAC?

I found this basic formula for calculating the amount of airflow needed to reach a target delta T:

```
CFM = (3.16 * Watts) / ΔT
```

So for a delta T of 10 degrees F -

```
CFM = (3.16 * 10kW) / 10
CFM = 3160
```

And for a delta T of 20 degrees F -

```
CFM = (3.16 * 10kW) / 20
CFM = 1580
```

It seems to me like both of these configurations should have the same effect on the room as it's the same 10kW of power producing heat. In the first configuration the exhaust would be 10 degrees higher than the room temperature, and in the second configuration the exhaust would be 20 degrees higher than the room temperature but exhausting at half the speed. With the lower speed, the heat transfer coefficient is lower as well, but I'm having trouble finding formulas for this when dealing with air to air heat transfer.

Do these different configurations have a different overall effect on the temperature of the room other than the area directly behind the server rack? Is that obviously hotter area directly behind the server rack different sized or just a different temperature gradient?

Comment: amount of *heat* same either way. Local *temperature* of exhaust will vary. Once mixed at the scale of the full room, load into the room HVAC will still be the same (barring something like having the exhaust placed right next to the thermostat or an open window or something like that) . The formula / relationship you might be looking for is the one between temperature, heat capacity, and thermal energy (i.e. heat)

Comment: This makes sense and is how I would expect it to be intuitively. So then does the delta T through the rack matter for anything else in the room? Disregarding the safe operating temperature of what's inside the rack, is a low or zero airflow the most cost efficient as far as the fans go (cheaper or no fans, less power to run)?

Comment: Kannst du keine Metrische Einheiten verwenden? Und bitte, überall die Einheit angeben. Das Formelzeichen für Leistung ist nicht Watts sondern P für Potentia (Lateinisch für Leistung). Watts wäre die Einheit Watt * sekunden (was gleich Joule ist). Was ist CFM für eine Grösse/Dimension?

Comment: @Chris - Yes, passive cooling typically more cost effective, and also more reliable. Air flow would not be exactly 0, due to the buoyancy of hot air. But as you point out, often not possible or practical (e.g. with unforced air = larger heat sink and more open space needed)...